# How do I list all groups a GCP service account belongs to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-iam

I have a GSA: `my-gsa@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

GCP has supported groups for a while now so I added that GSA to a bunch of groups.

How can I easily see what groups that GSA belongs to?

If this was a google *user* account I could go to the G Suite console and view the *user's* group membership. This is a GSA though and it does not appear in the G Suite console like that.

Ideally I could see this in some web console page or with gcloud. This gcloud command will show me the members of a group: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/identity/groups/memberships/list. How do I do the inverse of that, again for a GSA not a google user account?

## EDIT

Not a solution but a script to search all groups. Still think there has to be an API call to get this as a single step. The `groups.memberships.searchTransitiveGroups()` method I think is only for seeing nested group memberships.

```
GSA_TO_SEARCH=my-gsa@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
PROJECT_ID=projectname # This can be any project in the org
ORG_ID="$(gcloud projects get-ancestors $PROJECT_ID | grep organization | cut -f1 -d' ')"
# I don't think this label includes GCP security groups just G Suite email groups
GROUPS="$(gcloud beta identity groups search --organization=$ORG_ID --labels='cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum' --format='json')"
GROUP_EMAILS="$(echo $GROUPS | jq '.groups[] | .groupKey.id')"
echo $GROUP_EMAILS | \
    xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} && \
    gcloud beta identity groups memberships list --group-email="{}" --format=json | \
    jq '.[] | select(.memberKey.id==\"$GSA_TO_SEARCH\").memberKey.id'"
```

Comment: Is your question limited to a project or every resource in Google Cloud? For the first case, list the project's IAM binding and then process each group listed. For the second case, you would have to check each resource. For an organization, you might be able to use **gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies** and specify **--query='policy=GROUP_EMAIL_ADDRESS'** and then process the results. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/search-all-iam-policies

Comment: This doesn't even concern GCP resources or bindings. Groups are org level. I want to find all groups a GSA is a member of- obviously without manually listing the membership of ALL groups and checking each one for the user. It is possible to view group membership for a user through the G Suite console but thats only for Google users not GSAs that are created in GCP.

Comment: I am not aware of a method to list groups that a service account is a member of. As easy as that sounds, it is not. That is why I posted a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Check this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/query-memberships).
To find all of the groups that a member belongs to, call [groups.memberships.searchTransitiveGroups()](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/searchTransitiveGroups) with the member key (for example, the email address of the member).

Comment: Does gcloud not support this yet?

Comment: I couldn't find a gcloud command for that, however as adding service accounts to groups is [not a best practice](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts#groups) it may not get supported at all.